# Kendo File uploader not getting Controller method called

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-ui

I have file upload html code as:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("UploadImage", "PP", new AjaxOptions() { HttpMethod = "POST" }, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <input type="file" name="files">
    <button class="buttoncss">Upload</button>
    //<input type="submit" name="Submit to server">
    (also tried with input type="submit"
}
```

In PPController i have method as below:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public void UploadImage(IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> files)
{
    if (files != null)
    {
        foreach (var file in files)
        {
            // Verify that the user selected a file
            if (file != null && file.ContentLength > 0)
            {
                // extract only the fielname
                var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
                // TODO: need to define destination
                var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Upload"), fileName);
                file.SaveAs(path);
            }
        }
    }
```

But my controller method is not getting called.

What can be the problem?

Please help me.

Comment: Can you please show your java-script code.

Comment: @Saranga  no javascript code

Comment: Try adding `$(document).ready(function({$("input[name=files]").kendoUpload(); });`.

Comment: And make sure you have referenced required java-script libraries. (http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/upload/index).

Comment: I don't see you actually creating a Kendo Upload widget anywhere... but still, normal HTML form seems like it should be calling your controller. Does the browser try to send a request when you click the submit button? What URL does it try to post to? what is the server response?